# GROUP BY, then WHERE, then COUNT in SQL given a database

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, count

If we are given a database that looks like this:

Say table name: 'tbl'

| row # | course_id | eval_type | eval_date | Passed? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 000 | test1 | 2020-09-01 | Y |
| 2 | 001 | test2 | 2020-10-01 | N |
| 3 | 000 | test1 | 2020-09-02 | Y |
| 4 | 000 | test1 | 2020-10-11 | Y |
| 5 | 000 | test2 | 2020-09-01 | Y |
| 6 | 001 | test1 | 2020-10-01 | Y |

How can we write a query so that we get the number of courses where we passed both evaluations, test1 and test2, on the first try? (we can do the same evaluations multiple times)

For instance, from the data above, I want my query to print 1 -
since we passed test1 of course 000 on the first try (row 1),
and passed test2 of course 000 on the first try (row 5).
But, even though test1 of course 001 has passed on the first try (row 6), since test2 of course 001 has failed on the first try (row 2), we don't include course 001 as a count to our query result.

This is what I currently have:

```
    SELECT course_id, eval_type, min(date)
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY course_id, eval_type
```

Comment: depending on your dialect, if available, `first(passed) order by date` should help

Comment: Sample table data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: @jarlh Right! The expected result would be a single integer; the number of courses that satisfies the criterias

Comment: I assume `000: True; 001: False`, or possibly just `1`

Comment: what defines an "attempt?  course 000 and course 001 would never be true since 000's test2 failed 1st time?   or both tet1 and test 2 are taken on same date to define an attempt?

Comment: @xQbert An attempt is an evaluation attempt - it would either be of type test1 or test2

Comment: And that result is?

Comment: @jarlh It would be `1`

Comment: [`GROUP BY` is always _after_ `WHERE`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/196292/do-any-sql-dialects-permit-the-logical-sequence-of-select-clauses) - so to do a `WHERE` after a `GROUP BY` you need to use `HAVING` (if possible) - or nest the query inside another, or use a CTE - but `COUNT` _after_ (rather than _within_) a `GROUP BY` can often be done with JUST `COUNT( DISTINCT ... )`.

Comment: _"How can we write a query so that we get the number of courses where we passed both evaluations, test1 and test2, on the first try? (we can do the same evaluations multiple times)"_ - this problem description does not match your posted question-title

Comment: Also, can `eval_type` by anything else other than `'test1'` and `'test2'`? (if not, then why does it look like a textual column that allows free-input? do you have a `CHECK` constraint, a `RULE` or `DOMAIN` constraint that ensures only those 2 values can exist?) And are those values guaranteed to be distinct within each `course`? Can the same test be passed twice?

Comment: @Dai For a course, there are only two evaluation types: test1 and test2. These evaluations can be taken as many times possible, despite the outcome (pass/ fail). So, there could be multiple 'Passed' evalutions of the same type

Comment: One row, one column with the value 1. Add that to your question - don't expect people to look in the comments. Make it easy to assist you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a subquery to find the earliest date for each exam type and then finding the total number of passes:

```
select t.course_id from (select t1.course_id, sum(t2.passed = 'Y') r 
   from (select t.course_id, t.eval_type, min(t.eval_date) d from tbl t group by t.course_id, t.eval_type) t1 
   join tbl t2 on t1.course_id = t2.course_id and t1.eval_type = t2.eval_type and t1.d = t2.eval_date
group by t1.course_id) t where t.r = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Separate the query into two steps, first an "inner" query to get the first attempts, then an outer query to get "final result" - course_ids with two passed tests for their first attempts.

Examples:

###### Query 1

```
select X.course_id
from
(
    select 
        row_number() over (partition by course_id, eval_type order by date) as seq,
        course_id,
        eval_type,
        date,
        passed
from tbl
) X
where
    X.seq = 1
    and X.passed = 'Y'
group by 
    X.course_id
    having count(X.course_id) = 2
```

I do not attempt to resolve ties with this query. If two attempts can happen on the same day, one a pass and one a fail, then further logic should be added ...

###### Query 2

```
select distinct t1.course_id
from
(
    select 
        course_id,
        eval_type,
        min(date) as date
    from
        tbl
    group by
        course_id,
        eval_type
) t1
where not exists (
    select * 
    from tbl t2 
    where 
        t2.course_id = t1.course_id
        and t2.date = t1.date
        and t2.passed = 'N')
```

This query uses a correlated subquery approach (warning: this may be an inefficient query when there are many rows of data to work with). As a plus, compared to Query 1 above, it will continue to work if there are other tests, not just test1 and test2 - any initial failure on the date of the first attempts will exclude a course_id from the results.